# I want to use Scrapy Playwright to scrape content in different currencies

Tags: python, scrapy, playwright

I'm using Scrapy Playwright to scrape the following website: https://www.villabalisale.com/search/villas-for-sale

By default, the page displays the prices in USD, I want to incorporate Playwright in my Scrapy script, so I can change the price to IDR, and then scrape the prices in this currency.

However, I'm having issues finding documentation on this. If I'm using Playwright only the command is simple:

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright


with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=True)  # Launch headless browser
    page = browser.new_page()  # Open a new tab

    url = 'https://www.villabalisale.com/search/villas-for-sale'

    try:
        page.goto(url)

        # Click on the currency dropdown
        page.click('.header-cur')

        page.locator('text=IDR').first.click()

        # Take a screenshot
        page.screenshot(path='screenshot_1.png')

    finally:
        page.close()
```

But I don't know how to use it with my Scrapy spider:

```
"""This script contains the spider responsable for crawling Kibarer website"""
import scrapy
from scrapy_playwright.page import PageMethod


class KibarerVillasSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    """
    Spider class to extract information about the villas from Kibarer website.

    """

    name = 'kibarer_villas'
    page_number = 2

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://www.villabalisale.com/search/villas-for-sale'
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url,
            self.parse,
            meta={
                'playwright': True,
                'playwright_include_page': True,
                'playwright_page_methods': PageMethod(
                    "click", "li a", text="IDR")},
            errback=self.errback)

    async def parse(self, response):
        page = response.meta["playwright_page"]
        await page.close()

        for property in response.css('#box'):
            for tag in property.css('div.box.property-item'):
                yield {
                    'title': tag.css('div.name::text').get(),
                    'price': tag.css('div.price-holder::text').get(),
                }

    async def errback(self, failure):
        page = failure.request.meta["playwright_page"]
        await page.close()
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: The empty errback is masking the error you would otherwise see in the logs: `playwright_page_methods` should be an iterable of `PageMethod` objects, not a single one.
If you're not using the page in the callback, I suggest removing the `playwright_include_page=True` part, that allows you to remove the errback and the `page.close` call in the callback.